# Sending mail from dynamic web application in java

Tags: java, email, tomcat

I wanted to send email to other mail account such as hotmail, google from dynamic web application in java. I am using Tomcat as local server. How can I achieve from my local server by using Tomcat. I tried using JavaMail but it is not working. Is there any way to achieve this simply without adding additional servers.

Comment: What are your current dependencies added for sending out mails?

Comment: I have not added any dependencies. I have no idea about sending sending mails. I just wanted to send text via email to receiver. Basically, I am creating an web application for sending mails in java using tomcat as local sever. So, how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to have two dependencies in your classpath: javaee.jar and mail.jar. They are available on maven repository:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>mail</artifactId>
<version>1.4.7</version>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>7.0</version>
```

Secondly, for examples on using java mail api, check this link: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: thanks it work. Can you help me if there is anyway that I can send email to hotmail as well?